# Firefox crashes and website password verification

Tags: firefox, password

OS Linux 18.04.6 LTS, installed year ago on laptop.
Web browser - Firefox (latest).
problem #1 - firefox repeatedly crashes. About once a day, maybe more often. This problem was occurring for the last few months.

After trying to install Opera (to use instead of firefox), I didn't sucseed and installed Midori instead (within ubuntu software feature). OS was updated as well. Opera proxy is also installed, but I can't remove it now.

Problem #2 - every time I access a site where I need to log in (like Yahoo, ebay and the like), these sites as for an access code sent to my cell phone. After getting these access codes, I can enter aforementioned sites. This procedure is very inconvenient...!!!!
When computer goes to sleep and wakes up, I have to repeat all this nonsence with cell phone codes etc.

I feel that there is some kind of setting, private or the like, that was "activated" upon all these installations.

Can you, guys, help me in directing what I have to change, install in order to eliminate these problems.
My main goal was to use other web browser, instead of Firefox, in order to have seamless web browsing....

LAN settings - wireless connection...

Thanks...

Comment: There is not version 22.xx please correct. What a web site wants to do t authenticate has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 22.xx. Maybe it was 21.xx when I installed it last year, but, since the OS was updated, I assume it's 22.xx now.

Comment: There has never been a version of Ubuntu call anything .xx. An actual version number is needed to offer any help.

Comment: And it must be reiterated "problem #2" not a problem at all and NOTHING to do with Ubuntu. The 2-step identification is either mandatory for the sites you're authenticating on or it was enabled by you, end of story. You should [edit] the question, post the correct Ubuntu release/version, whether it was upgraded from a previous release and other relevant information like describing exactly what happens with Firefox and even try running Firefox from the terminal and posting the error messages in full.

Comment: Correction- version is 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: before today authentication was done once, the first time I opened any particular site. This was similar to authentication when you enter (log in) from a different computer. today the sites ask for cell phone code authentication every time I open site's window, even if I switch to a different window (multiple windows).

Comment: ChangeanAuto - tell me how to run Firefox from terminal, please.

Comment: I opened Terminal, typed in "firefox", new firefox window opened. no error message....